# Scheduled tasks in Jetty

Tags: java, groovy, jetty, quartz-scheduler

I would like to write a simple Groovlet which runs a task periodically and am using a Jetty container. What's the easiest way to accomplish this task? I'm thinking that Quartz should be used but I'm not sure how it integrates with Jetty. Do I need to create a control panel for starting and stopping the tasks? Are there any simple examples that I can look at to get started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a job config file "jobconf.xml" or a property file, in which the jobs must be configured. This file must be added  into either application's classpath or jetty's.

You have to add QuartzInitializer into your web.xml and the servlet params like following:

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
<display-name>Quartz Initializer Servlet</display-name>
<servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
<init-param>
<param-name>config-file</param-name>
<param-value>quartz.properties</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

<init-param>
<param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>

</servlet>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>first</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.v2sol.StartQuartz</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>first</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/fst</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.v2sol.ExcelDBServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>cronExpr</param-name>
<param-value>0,30 * * ? * MON-FRI</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>one</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/excel</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

and the usage scheduler in your servlet :

```
System.out.println("Initializing Scheduler PlugIn for Jobs!");
super.init(config);
ServletContext ctx = config.getServletContext();
Scheduler scheduler = null;
StdSchedulerFactory factory = (StdSchedulerFactory) 
ctx.getAttribute(QuartzInitializerServlet.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);  

try {   
scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
JobDetail jd = new JobDetail("job1", "group1",ExcelJob.class);  
CronTrigger cronTrigger = new CronTrigger("trigger1","group1");
String cronExpr = null;
cronExpr = getInitParameter("cronExpr");
System.out.println(cronExpr);   
cronTrigger.setCronExpression(cronExpr);
scheduler.scheduleJob(jd, cronTrigger);
System.out.println("Job scheduled now ..");

} catch (Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A simpler solution than Quartz is to use the Timer and TimerTask classes provided by the JDK. They don't provide as wide a variety of scheduling options, but if you just want to run a task at fixed intervals, they should suffice.

If you need a console to stop start the task, you'll either need to write that yourself, or write a JMX bean that provides access to the Timer and use the JMX console to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Quartz scheduler and put it in the application context. Any Groovlet will be having access to it and will be able to submit new tasks and manipulate running ones.